# Recursive relations – how to build list properly?

Tags: templating, entrymodel, twigextension

I started building a list of recursive relations:

We're in a project, we want to check interviews related to that project, see which persons participated in those related interviews, and then build an ordered list of all those persons – without duplicates.

My first approach was to combine two loops:

```
{% set relatedInterviews = craft.entries.section('interviews').relatedTo(entry).all() %}  
{% if relatedInterviews %}  
{% set interviewedpersons = [] %}
  {% for interview in relatedInterviews %}
    {% set relatedPersons = craft.entries.section('persons').relatedTo(interview).all() %}
    {% for person in relatedPersons %}
      {% set interviewedpersons = interviewedpersons|merge([person]) %}
    {% endfor %} 
  {% endfor %}

  {% for interviewedperson in interviewedpersons %}
    <a href="{{interviewedperson.url}}">{{interviewedperson.firstname}}{{interviewedperson.lastname}}</a>{% if loop.last %}{% else %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In PHP, we would now sort and clear duplicates from `interviewedpersons`, but I see in twig the array sorting possibilities are a bit reduced, right? Probably because building such a list is already more of a controller than a view / template thing?

So is there a better approach to do this double relation, sorting and avoiding duplicates via Craft's Entrymodel?

What about

```
{% set relatedPersons = craft.entries.section('persons').relatedTo(craft.entries.section('interviews').relatedTo(entry)).orderBy('lastname asc, firstname asc').all() %}
{% for relatedPerson in relatedPersons %}
   <a href="{{relatedPerson.url}}">{{relatedPerson.firstname}}{{relatedPerson.lastname}}</a>{% if loop.last %}{% else %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

– much better? I'm pleasantly surprised this works. Do I have to check for empty bits, and will duplicates be removed already?